# Make [csp] a synonym of [content-security-policy]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

There is no need for [csp](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/csp) and [content-security-policy](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/content-security-policy) to co-exist, as one is just the abbreviation of the other. For some reason, I can't make [csp](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/csp) a synonym of [content-security-policy](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/content-security-policy), stating I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Agree! Both about the synonym, and keeping the long as the main tag.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have merged csp into content-security-policy and set the synonym.

Aside: this can be done without moderator intervention via enough upvotes on a tag synonym.

Comment: For some reason, I was not able to create the synonym, even though I had points in [tag:content-security-policy]. But I am glad this is resolved now.

Answer (score 5):

While I agree that in the world of web appsec, `CSP == Content Security Policy`, I'm not sure that's true in all areas of information security.

Taking a look at [the wikipedia disambiguation page for CSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSP), the following jump out as potential legitimate uses of "CSP" on this site:

- **Credential Service Provider** -- seems to be a US Gov term for an authority who issues any kind of e-credentials.
- **Critical Security Parameter** -- Defined in FIPS 140-2 as `"Critical security parameter (CSP): security-related information (e.g., secret and private cryptographic keys,and authentication data such as passwords and PINs) whose disclosure or modification can compromise the security of a cryptographic module."`
- **Cryptographic Service Provider** -- A Microsoft Windows term for CAPI-like plugins.
- **Cloud Service Provider** -- synonym for Cloud Computing.

Comment: That's true, and I understand the potential hazards. Should it turn out to be a problem, we'll have to retag and deprecate [tag:csp]. We used to have a similar problem, where people used the tag [tag:policy] on content security policies all the time.